# Converting a matrix into a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, dplyr

I am trying to find convert/cast a built in matrix state.x77 to a dataframe. But once casted using as.data.frame, the column "Life Exp" should be automatically casted to "Life.Exp"; however, when i used select() function to choose that column using Life.Exp or Life Exp, both do not exist. Am I casting it wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
state.x77 %>% as.data.frame %>% select(Frost,Life.Exp) %>% cor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as.data.frame` surprisingly does not change name of columns so the space in it remains, you can `select` the column with back quotes.

```
library(dplyr)
state.x77 %>% as.data.frame %>% select(Frost,`Life Exp`) %>% cor
```

However, if you use `data.frame` it adds the `"."` in between so now you can use

```
state.x77 %>% data.frame %>% select(Frost,Life.Exp) %>% cor
```

Comment: thak you sir, soo data.frame is different from as.data.frame how?

Comment: They are almost the same except for very minor cases like these.

Answer (score 1):

Reinforcing the response of colleagues, as.data.frame converts the state.x77 matrix to data.frame, keeping the name of the original variables. The Life Exp variable contains space, interpreted by the R as a special character, so to select the Life Exp column in the data.frame, you must put (``). Therefore:

```
select (Frost, `Life Exp`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
state.x77 %>% as.data.frame() %>% select(Frost,`Life Exp`) %>% cor()

            Frost Life Exp
Frost    1.000000 0.262068
Life Exp 0.262068 1.000000
```